# Hide/Show stackpanel on click on a button using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using MVVM for the first time and I am not using any framwork for that.
I have a view which has a stackpanel and that stackpanel has children with a button. 
I want to click that button and hide the stackpanel and all its children. I am using

**InteractionTriggers** but that is not helping me ! kindly check and assist where I am doing wrong

> View.XAML

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
              Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MenuAppMemTopApps1" Height="485" Width="534">
        <StackPanel Height="80.667" Margin="1.767,0,0,0" 
                    Visibility="{Binding TopAppsTwitterCommand,Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visible}}">
            <TextBlock Margin="129.249,6,24,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       FontSize="17.333" Foreground="#FF8FA3AD" Text="7%" 
                       Height="28.408" RenderTransformOrigin="0.458,0.526" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="32.751"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" 
                       Text="Angry Birds" Height="28.408" Width="134.499" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,-29,0,3"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnRestartWiFi1_Copy19" Content="Repair Now" 
                    Height="32" Width="118" Background="#FFCED7DB" 
                    FontSize="13.333" Margin="24,6,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding repairAppsUsingBatteryCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
            <Image x:Name="image18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" 
                   Margin="24,-109,0,0" Width="24" 
                   Source="/WindowsDeviceAssist;component/Images/Angry-Birds-Logo.png"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

VM.CS

```
public VM() 
{ 
    this.repairAppsUsingBatteryCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecuterepairAppsUsingBatteryCommand);
}

private void ExecuterepairAppsUsingBatteryCommand(object obj)
{
    this.TopAppsTwitterCommand = false;
}  

public ICommand repairAppsUsingBatteryCommand { get; set; }

private bool topAppsTwitterCommand;
public bool TopAppsTwitterCommand
{
    get { return this.topAppsTwitterCommand; }
    set { this.healthTabCommand = true; }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by hiding ? Visibility = Hidden/Collapsed, or Opacity is ok ?

Comment: Visibility=Collapsed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a lot of value in using an `EventTrigger` here.

You can just do this:

```
<Button x:Name="btnRestartWiFi1_Copy19" 
        Content="Repair Now" Height="32" 
        Width="118" Background="#FFCED7DB" 
        FontSize="13.333" Margin="24,6,0,0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Command="{Binding repairAppsUsingBatteryCommand}" />
```

Also your `VM` class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so the UI will be notified about the change of `TopAppsTwitterCommand` property.

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

And the property:

```
private bool _topAppsTwitterCommand;
public bool TopAppsTwitterCommand
{
    get { return this._topAppsTwitterCommand; }
    set
    {
         this._topAppsTwitterCommand = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("TopAppsTwitterCommand");
    }
}
```

You had `this.healthTabCommand = true;` for some reason.

The rest of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: what about that stackpanel Visibility ? is that fine ?

Comment: If `Bool2Visible` converter is written correctly, meaning it converts `false` to `Visibility.Collapsed` or `Visibility.Hidden` and converts `true` to `Visibility.Visible`, then yes, taht should be OK.

Comment: Also I suggest proper variable/property names. `TopAppsTwitterCommand` sounds like an `ICommand` although it's a `bool`. It should be something like `IsTopAppsTwitterVisible` or something like that. I don't know the context of your application.

Comment: If you made the changes I suggested, it should work. If you put a breakpoint in `ExecuterepairAppsUsingBatteryCommand`, will that be hit?

Comment: Check your `RelayCommand` implementation. Please update your question with that. Also, the `DataContext` of the `Window` or `UserControl` or whatever you're in should be set to an instance of the class `VM` for the bindings to work.

Comment: actually this is not the only command for binding..I have binded other properties and they are working very well so the VM implementation is fine ! can we come in chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102797/discussion-between-szabolcs-dezsi-and-apoorv).

Answer (score 0):

We will use `Animation` to set `Visibility` of `StackPanel` to `Collapsed` using following approach.

Define a static field in your ViewModel.

```
    public static Visibility Collapsed = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Markup

> xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mynamespace"

```
  <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnRestartWiFi1_Copy19">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Stk1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>-->
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static local:ViewModel.Collapsed}">
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                            
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
   <StackPanel x:Name="MenuAppMemTopApps1" Height="485" Width="534">
   ...
```